# After Sitecore login, Sitecore.Current.User.IsAuthenticated always returns false on redirect to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I have no expereince in Sitecore but I need to fix this issue:
Basically we are logging the user in through ADFS and then creating a virtual user through Sitecore and logging him in:

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user =     
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(@"extranet\" + membershipUser.LastName, true);

if (user != null)
{
    string domainRole = @"extranet\externaluser";
    if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.Exists(domainRole))
    {
        user.Roles.Add(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName(domainRole));
    }

    Sitecore.Security.UserProfile profile = user.Profile;
    profile.FullName = membershipUser.FirstName + " " + membershipUser.LastName;

    bool islogin =  Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(user);
    AuthenticationManager.Login(user.Name,true );
    profile.Save();
}
```

At this point, if I check `Sitecore.Current.User.IsAuthenticated`, it returns true. If I navigate to another page, `Sitecore.Current.User.IsAuthenticated` returns false. We are not logging anyone out at this point.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed:
I had to change

```
<add name="SessionAuthenticationModule"  
type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule,    
System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

to

```
<add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" 
type="ADFS.Authenticator.Authentication.WsSessionAuthenticationModule, 
ADFS.Authenticator" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing it. Are you using MVC?

Try checking Sitecore.Context.User as opposed to Current.

```
public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        var domainUser = _domain.Name + @"\" + userName;
        try
        {
            var user = Business.Authenticate(userName, password);
            if (user == null) return false;

            var scuser = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(domainUser, true);

            if (scuser != null)
            {
                AuthenticationManager.Login(scuser);
                scuser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Add(Constants.UserRole);
                scuser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(Constants.UserEmail, user.Email);
                scuser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(Constants.UserId, user.UserId);

                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Diagnostics.Logger.Error(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. this does not work as we are redirecting to corpsts to ADFS login. If we skip this step, it works fine. This is an asp.net application, not MVC.